# Generating a British date/time pubDate for an RSS in Python

Tags: python, date, python-2.7, time, rss

I have some code creating an RSS feed, but I have an issue with generating a publication date

```
<pubDate>%s</pubDate>
```

How can I create a function or use a function to get the current date and time but in the British date/time format?

Thanks in advance
- Hyflex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Script:

```
import datetime

def pubdate(tag):
    return '<{tag}>{date}</{tag}>'.format(
        date = datetime.date.today().strftime("%d %B %Y"),
        tag = tag
    )
```

Demo:

```
print pubdate('pubDate')
```

Output:

```
<pubDate>17 June 2013</pubDate>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I've slightly modified it to how I needed it as seen below.


`import datetime
import time

def pubdate():
    return '{pubdate} {pubtime}'.format(
        pubdate = datetime.date.today().strftime("%d %B %Y"),
        pubtime = time.strftime('%H:%M')
    )`

Comment: That's OK, I'm glad I could help.